# How to open telegram account using phone number in android programatically(Using Intent)

Tags: android

I am creating a android application. I have some phone numbers list. And i try to open telegram account using particular phone number from list. So please give solution programatically in android.

I try this code for telegram but i have no username or user_id for open telegram account.

Please give solution.

```
                    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                    String url = "http://telegram.me/" ;
                    i.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
```

Comment: This is not possible sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INTENT.ACTION_VIEW, URI()`.
Here you can add your telegram link. so it would open telegram.